# The following assertion was thrown building HomePage(state: _HomePageState#fed07): No MediaQuery widget ancestor found

Tags: android, flutter, dart, widget

This is my main.dart file, and I'm trying to do Application for notifications based on Location. Everything was going well, then I refreshed the app and I saw an error. I tried to  pack widget, return, etc. in MaterialApp, but it didn't worked.

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:goe_notifications_new/search_places_screen.dart';

import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:native_notify/native_notify.dart';


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState(){
    return _HomePageState();
  }
}
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  NativeNotify.initialize(624, 'sVEBBLTwolG1bSazpSwXa2', null);
  runApp(HomePage());
}


class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  LatLng _initialPosition = LatLng(37, -122);
  late GoogleMapController controller;
  Location _location = Location();
  Marker _destination = Marker(markerId: const MarkerId('destination'));

  // @override
  // void dispose() {
  //   controller.dispose();
  //   super.dispose();
  // }

  Future createAlertDialog(BuildContext context){

    TextEditingController customController = TextEditingController();

    return showDialog(context: context, builder: (context){
      return AlertDialog(
        title: const Text("Your Todo"),
        content: TextField(
          controller: customController,
        ),
        actions: [
          MaterialButton(
              elevation: 5.0,
              child: const Text('Add TODO'),
              onPressed : (){
                // debugPrint("Hello");
                Navigator.of(context).pop(customController.text.toString());
              }
          )
        ],
      );
    });
  }




  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController _cntrl) {
    controller = _cntrl;
    _location.onLocationChanged.listen((l) {
      controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
        CameraPosition(target: LatLng(l.latitude!, l.longitude!),
            zoom: 15
        ),
      ),
      );
    });
  }
  void _gotodestination(GoogleMapController _cntrl) {
    controller = _cntrl;
    _cntrl.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(target: _destination.position,zoom: 14.5, tilt: 50 ),),);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: false,
        title: const Text("GeoNavigation"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(
                Icons.search_outlined
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: GoogleMap(initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: _initialPosition, zoom: 10),
        // onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
        zoomControlsEnabled: false,
        markers: {
          if (_destination != null) _destination
        },
        onLongPress: _addMarker,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          foregroundColor: Colors.black,
          onPressed: () {createAlertDialog(context).then((onValue){
            SnackBar mySnackBar = SnackBar(content: Text("Added $onValue to TODOS"));
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(mySnackBar);
          });
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.note_add)
      ),


    );



  }
  void submit(){
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
  void _addMarker(LatLng pos){
    setState((){
      _destination = Marker(
        markerId: const MarkerId('destination'),
        infoWindow: const InfoWindow(title:  'destination with 50m radius'),
        position: pos,
      );
    });
  }
}
```

And this is the Error, I've got when I Turn off the Emulator and refreshed the app:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building HomePage(state: _HomePageState#fed07):
No MediaQuery widget ancestor found.

Scaffold widgets require a MediaQuery widget ancestor.
The specific widget that could not find a MediaQuery ancestor was: Scaffold
  dirty
  state: ScaffoldState#a94f6(lifecycle state: initialized, tickers: tracking 2 tickers)
The ownership chain for the affected widget is: "Scaffold ← HomePage ← [root]"

No MediaQuery ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to MediaQuery.of(). This can happen because you have not added a WidgetsApp, CupertinoApp, or MaterialApp widget (those widgets introduce a MediaQuery), or it can happen if the context you use comes from a widget above those widgets.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  HomePage HomePage:file:///C:/Users/simon_134zsx/AndroidStudioProjects/goe_notifications_new/lib/main.dart:18:10
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      debugCheckHasMediaQuery.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:230:7)
#1      debugCheckHasMediaQuery (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:245:4)
#2      MediaQuery.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/media_query.dart:859:12)
#3      ScaffoldState.didChangeDependencies (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:2649:50)
#4      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4914:11)
#5      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4729:5)
#6      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3790:14)
#7      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3524:20)
#8      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4780:16)
#9      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4928:11)
#10     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#11     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2659:19)
#12     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:882:21)
#13     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:363:5)
#14     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#15     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1081:9)
#16     SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:862:7)
(elided 4 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, and dart:async-patch)
```

Please Help me Thanks :>